# IBM MQ failed error 2058

Tags: ibm-mq

I'm new with MQ Series and then tried to start with the "Hello World" 
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q030200_.htm

I execute it with linux as follow :

```
helloworld pQueueName QueueName SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN/TCP/hostname\(1414\)
```

I get this error message `ImqQueuemanager::connect failed with reset reason code 2058.`

The API say this error code is due to a wrong queue manager name.
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21166938

Then : Why do I have a such message and what do they mean by "wrong queue manager name"?

Comment: The queue manager name you provided does not match with the one running at localhost(1414).What is the name of the queue manager you have created?

Comment: I thought the program would create the queue thanks to the "SetName" method.
I didn't create one for now, how should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, queue manager and queues must be created explicitly before you can use them. The setName method points to queue manager to connect to and does not create a queue manager.

Watch this video from T.Rob on how to install MQ and use it - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wSCHLBftjDw&pbjreload=10. In the video Linux OS is used. That's OK. You can skip the setup part (up to 2 minutes and 20 seconds or so) and start following from crtmqm command.

Comment: I've already watched it but thought there were a way using only c++
Thank you very much, I close the topic.